# How to config laravel app subdomains in shopify?

Tags: laravel, shopify, shopify-app

I have an example domain named https:// domainexp.com in which I create a folder named ShopifyApp and in that folder create another laravel framework project named laravel1. If you want to run the laravel directory, you need to go to their public directory as https://domainexp.com/ShopifyApp/laravel1/public
and when creating a new app we need to fill in the domain information as App Url: https://domainexp.com but the directory laravel can run is
https://domainexp.com/ShopifyApp/laravel1/public so my domain path information is
App Url: https://domainexp.com/ShopifyApp/laravel1/public
and the path to validate Allowed redirection URL(s) :
https://domainexp.com/ShopifyApp/laravel1/public/authenticate.
after creating the app I see that in the frame just displayed is the path to https://domainexp.com/ and not the laravel directory. How can I properly point to the laravel path to create an app?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l1NP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9EnB.png)

Best regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I have corrected the question hope you can understand.